# which is the best board with ros

Tags: ros, arduino, odroid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi dear
I want to use ros on a board like beagleboard,odroid,cubie board
but I do not have enough information about ros and the boards
can some one help me which board is the best and why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93936/which-is--the-best-board-with-ros/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2013-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-24**:
We're using an Intel NUC board with a Core i3. Works like a charm.

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2013-10-24**:
Hi Hendrik
could you tell me about details of this board
which version of linux you use on it?
and how hard is working with it ?

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-25**:
It's a pretty neat small board with an mSATA and two memory slots and a Core i3 processor. Here's /proc/cpuinfo of the board: http://pastebin.com/ysmZjgU5 Working with it is like on a normal PC. Ubuntu 13.04 64bit runs pretty well on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depends on what you want to do with it. There is are instructions for the [beagleboard](http://wiki.ros.org/BeagleBoard) and the [Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20ROS%20on%20RaspberryPi). But it depends on your application if those boards have enough computing power.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0